# Syntax confusion about code in pip installer, "get-pip.py"

Tags: python, syntax, installation, pip

When looking at the `pip` installer [`get-pip.py`](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) found on [this page](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing.html) I noticed a bit of syntax that I'm unfamiliar with.

Found on line 17422 of the file, this is the line:

```
packages += ["setuptools"]
```

I'm confused as to why it uses the odd `+=` syntax instead of the `.append()`
method. I've never seen this style of adding a string to a list of strings
before, and I'm wondering why it's used here. Why not have this line read:

```
packages.append("setuptools")
```

I suspect this is done for compatibility reasons, or it's an artifact of history. Does anyone know the origin or cause of this syntax? If not, where could I learn more about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is basically very little difference  performance  wise.

```
In [9]: %%timeit 
   ...: packages=[]
   ...: packages+=["setuptools"]
   ...: 
10000000 loops, best of 3: 155 ns per loop

In [10]: %%timeit 
   ....: packages=[]
   ....: packages.append("setuptools")
   ....: 
10000000 loops, best of 3: 123 ns per loop
```

Where `+=` comes in handy is if you want to append more than one item without appending sublists:

```
In [11]: packages=[]

In [12]: packages += ["setuptools","other"]

In [13]: packages
Out[13]: ['setuptools', 'other']

In [14]: packages=[]

In [15]: packages.append(["setuptools","other"])

In [16]: packages
Out[16]: [['setuptools', 'other']]
```

Using `extend v +=`:

```
In [52]: 
%%timeit packages=[]
packages.extend( ["setuptools","other"])
   ....: 
10000000 loops, best of 3: 173 ns per loop

In [53]: 
%%timeit packages=[]
packages += ["setuptools","other"]
   ....: 
10000000 loops, best of 3: 130 ns per loop
```

Comment: That second block of code really helps to demonstrate how this syntax *can* make code clearer. Thanks for the explanation on this, I realize it's odd and/or might not quite fit with the StackOverflow style. In the future, do you have any recommendations as to where I may ask similar questions in the future? Or is StackOverflow the appropriate place for these?

Comment: @lelandbatey, I don't think your question is off-topic, if you search something like `list.append v += python` you would probably get a good  few hits. Best thing to do is search and if you don't find an answer then feel free to ask.

Comment: You can append more then one element with `list.extend` so there is no limitation. `extend` also performs on par with lists concatenation with `+` operator, resp. `__add__` method.

Comment: @DavidUnric, so you downvoted a correct answer? The question is about append v +=, not extend v +=. Also in our example += is faster so you are wrong on that also.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Your answer does not explain OP's question, ie. why devs did decided to use `+` operator. `list.append` is not an equivalent, whereas not mentioned `list.extend` is. Performance wise I hope you understand what *on par* means. For this use case the speed difference is negligible so argumenting with performance reasons is bit ridiculous.

Comment: I answered the question showing there is very little difference in either += or append and how append and += can have different outcomes when adding more than 1 element so why don't you add an answer if you know of some major difference in using append or += in the example.